# map to render grid in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What are the different values that row and ri take in the code in the return part of the code and how does that help in rendering.I have a very vague idea of how to deal with a map when it comes to a matrix where things works in 2d ways .
Here is the code for the component.

```
class Game extends React.Component{
  render(){
     let matrix=[];
     let row;
     for(var i=0;i<this.props.rows;i++){
       row=[];
       for(var j=0;j<this.props.columns;j++){
         row.push(`${i}${j}`)
       }
       matrix.push(row);
     }
     return(
       <div className="grid">

       {
         matrix.map((row, ri) => (

          <Row key={ri}>
          {row.map(cellId => <Cell key={cellId} id={cellId} />)}
           </Row>
          ))
        }

       </div>

     );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for implementing a standard html table.
The 2nd parameter (`ri` in your code) in map function is index. It can be used as a key as long as you don't remove the data. If you need to manipulate the data, then it is not a suitable key.

If you are sure the 1st column in each row are unique, you can use `row[0]` as a key.
Here is an example:

```
const data = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9],
];

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        {
          data.map((row, index) => (
            <tr key={row[0]}>
              {row.map(cellId => <th key={cellId}>{cellId}</th>)}
            </tr>
          ))
        }
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

There is the code demo:

[image: Edit new]